# Module Replacement (Linodef)

Tags: 7, updating

Does anyone know of a good replacement for the [Linodef](http://drupal.org/project/linodef) module?  We are upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and need to figure out a way to replace the functionality of Linodef.  I've tried updating the module, but this seems to be a daunting task.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.